# Empty folder still persists after recursively deleting using fs.rmdir

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs

I'm trying to delete a folder recursively but the folder itself is still there (empty) when using `fs.rmdir(dest, { recursive: true });`
Has anyone else come across this issue and if so how did you manage to fix it?

I'm using `Node v14.17.0`

Comment: Are you sure there are no hidden files in it or files that you don't have permissions on or files that some process has an open file handle on?

Comment: No hidden files and I have root privileges but it could potentially be another process not letting me perform the deletion since I've tried other libraries like `rimraf` and the problem still persisted. Is there a way to check what processes have an open handle on the folder or force the deletion?

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: If Windows Explorer is open and pointing at that directory, it won't let you delete it.

Comment: I don't think it's file explorer for me, I had it pointing a directory above the one that is being deleted and even closed it entirely but the problem still happened.

However, I managed to come up with a hacky solution using the callback method
Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky solution to anyone else having the same issue:

```
fs.rmdir(dest, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    try {
        if (fs.existsSync(dest)) fs.unlinkSync(dest);
    } catch (e) {
        // handle error
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: `if (err) throw err;` is not helping you at all.  You should pretty much never write that in an asynchronous callback as nobody can catch it or do anything with it and it may just be ignored or it may shut-down your app.